how to run EventCreate command in DockerFile for Docker Windows
I have the command:
eventcreate /t error /id 1000 /so ExceptionManagerInternalException /l application /d "new ExceptionManagerInternalException src in application log"
And I need to run it when I raise the Docker image, using the DockerFile, but I haven't been able to make it work, I have tried putting these lines in my dockerFile.
But I have not been able to since it throws me different errors that kill the execution of the Docker container
I've tried putting this in my DockerFile, but nothing works:
RUN eventcreate.exe /t error /id 1000 /so ExceptionManagerInternalException /l application /d "new src ExceptionManagerInternalException in application log"
CMD ["eventcreate","/t error","/id 1000","/so ExceptionManagerInternalException","/l application","/d new src ExceptionManagerInternalException in application log"]

since it throws me different errors that kill the execution of the Docker container Can you copy the error text I to your Question body?
